# A drop falling in the condensed air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, mass

A drop is falling in humid air with air resistance equal $F_r = - \alpha v^2$. In $t = 0$ the drop is ideally spherical, $h$ above the ground, has mass $m_0$ and velocity $v_0 = 0$.

What mass and velocity will the drop have when it reaches the ground? Which additional information do we need to know to solve this problem?

My progress so far: the change of the drop's momentum equals $$dp = m dv + v dm$$
Hence $$F = m \dot{v} + v \dot{m}$$
But $$F = mg - \alpha \dot{x}^2$$
Hence $$ \alpha \dot{x}^2 + m\ddot x + \dot x \dot m= mg$$

Now it remains to find $\dot m$, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is categorized as a "homework problem"; if you want to attract good answers, you should probably spend a little time showing what work you've put into solving it.

Comment: The drop will not be spherical, and you need to qualify the relative humidity before a calculation can be done regarding the evaporation rate of the drop.

Comment: True but anything below 2 mm seems fairly spherical: http://pmm.nasa.gov/education/articles/shape-of-a-raindrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here is to find enough expressions for $\dot m$.

Here are some hints:

1: Define some constants first (such as mass density of raindrop, mass density of water droplets in space)!

2: Express $\dot m$ in two different ways, one using attributes of spherical geometry, another using the rate at which the raindrop picks up water droplets as it travels. Define your variables carefully here!

3. Set up some differential equations and solve! The result is surprisingly simple. You will find that the acceleration of raindrop is INDEPENDENT of any of the constants that we named... cough cough.

Have fun with the problem. If you are really stuck, check out [David Morin's textbook: Introduction to Classical Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521876222), Chapter 5, approximately problem 5.28.

Answer (score 0):

Since as you're stating *humid air* ("condensed", even), why not assume net evaporation doesn't occur, so $\dot{m}=0$?

Then set up a simple Newtonian equation of motion ($x$-axis is the vertical):

$$F_{net}=ma$$

$$mg-\alpha v^2=ma$$

$$mg-\alpha \dot{x}^2=m\frac{d\dot{x}}{dt}$$

Which is separable.

And for low velocities you could also use [Stokes Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law#Statement_of_the_law), which gives the air drag as $F_r$:

$$F_r=6\pi \eta R \dot{x},$$

with $\eta$ the air viscosity and $R$ the drop's radius.

Comment: Well, I mean that the drop increases its mass, catching the humid air

Comment: @InvolutiveAutomorphism: if the air is saturated with moisture then the drop will only grow if its temperature is *below* the air's temperature. But I've no idea how to calculate that growth. And as David White pointed out: large drops won't be spherical but flattened.